# How to start MainActivity every time from Launcher Icon?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

A quick question:

I want to launch my `MainActivity` every time when I launch my application. That is restart the application when pressing the launcher icon.

Currently if I press home button in between, and when I press the launcher icon of my application, it takes to wherever I've left previously.

I've tried below approaches:

Add below code in `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    this.finish();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.finish();
}
```

Add below lines in `Manifest.xml`:

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```

But nothing works. And suggestion?

Comment: basically u wanna finish all activity when app closes?

Comment: u have to call `finish()` in `onPause()` method. More info - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Comment: @DIVA: Yea. Exactly.

Comment: can u go through this --> [blog](http://steveliles.github.io/is_my_android_app_currently_foreground_or_background.html) here mentioned that how to check app went to background

Answer (score -1):

use  android:launchMode="singleInstance" with your launcher activity.